# Why is this less profitable for an adventurer to craft and then sell an artefact, rather than to sell ingredients needed to craft the artefact?

Tags: economy, low-fantasy

Suppose we have standard world of fantasy RPG videogame. The MC (main character) earns money by killing monsters and then selling loot. Also, sometimes there are people happy to pay generous reward for slaughter of especially vicious monster. As an adventurer they **aren't** a member of any guild.

The MC can also craft artefacts. Some ingredients can be bought, some can be collected (like herbs), some can be stolen, some can be harvested from dead monsters. And then from these ingredients an artefact can be crafted by the MC and then sold. If total cost of ingredients needed for crafting an artefact < market price of the artefact, then the MC can get profit. But for some strange reason it is always more profitable for the MC to just sell ingredients at their market price, than to craft an artefact from them and then sell it at market price. Why? Especially considering that there seem to be people in this world who find it more profitable to sell crafted artefacts, rather than sell ingredients needed to craft them (otherwise no new artefacts would be available for sale).

P.S. I'm not a writer, I just encountered this situation in a videogame RPG and wanted to see somehow realistic explanation for such situation. For this reason crafting system of the game doesn't matter.

Comment: How standard is your video game? And how the crafting system works? The accepted answer would not work in a typical RPG.

Comment: Yeah much as I love the big green tick there are other great ideas here too.

Comment: If it takes X time to find and sell the ingredients for \$50 but 3X time to craft it and sell for \$100 then you're missing out on \$50. This is why hammer manufacturers don't just hoard all the hammers and build houses themselves.

Comment: One thing the accepted answer seems to be assuming is that crafting always succeeds and there is no failures. Once you start accounting for failures that can drastically change the equation.

Comment: Are you writing a fantasy book based on video-game economics? If so, is it meant to be funny (video game crating has plenty of funny parts in how they fail to makes sense). Or do you want your character to make and sell things, but are wondering about any obstacles?

Comment: Real-world example of this: in Runescape unrefined ores often cost more than refined bars because a lot of people like to buy ores, smelt them to grind XP, and sell the resulting bars. Metal armor and weapons are often cheaper than bars for the same reason.

Comment: VTC: This question is not answerable in its current form and leads to answers based on speculation. You need to [edit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/207106/edit) your query to include detailed explanations of the crafting and market systems: How exactly crafting works, how the markets work (player-driven and NPC-driven markets work very differently and result in different phenomena).

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that if a sword actually sold for *less* than its components, you could make money by buying swords and smelting them down. The unprofitability must therefore come from the costs of actually making the sword (time, forge fee, ...).

Comment: @OwenReynolds I'm not a writer, I just encountered this situation in a videogame RPG and wanted to see somehow realistic explanation for such situation.

Comment: You have received many good answers about "why would be adventurer unable to get realistic market price for his creation" and accepted one of them too. Is this what you were after, or do you want specific "raw materials are MORE expensive than the finished product (from a shop)"? (which has some answers too, most along the line of "skilled smith wastes less material")

Comment: In many videogame RPGs you can't melt swords back down.

Comment: So,  you want an in-universe explanation for the market effects at play between out-of-universe actors, the players? Because, as others already hinted to, skill and experience gain on crafting is usually a major driver for raw material prices.

Comment: I'm tempted to add an answer of the form "because the [labor theory of value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labor_theory_of_value) is empirically incorrect, so go read up on [subjective value theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjective_theory_of_value) and [comparative advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_advantage) instead." But that's a bit too short for a real answer.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

#### Because the adventure's skill and reputation is always below that of a specialized craftsman.

Bob the Blacksmith has been making swords all his life. He's spent 40 years perfecting the art of the turning metal into blades of death. He knows how to manage the furnace and molten metal and his collection of special hammers in order to create a wonderful sword.

He's known and trusted. Carl says: "Bob's sword saved me from a bandit last year. I never go anywhere without it!". Everyone trusts Carl.

Mr Adventurer walks into town with a clump of a magic metal ingots and blessed artifacts. Uses the town forge to knock up a sword that sounds good on paper, but being made by someone who hasn't spent 40 years making swords its unlikely to be of such high quality. Did he remember to quench between impacts? Did he cool it down too fast too harden it correctly, or too slow? Did he use the right blend of wood and coal?

Also Mr Adventurer may have a reputation for saving the town from the dragon, but Mr Adventurer doesn't have a reputation for making quality swords yet. Nobody has used his swords before, they're unknown.

As a new entrant to the market, Mr Adventurer can only sell his goods at a discount. Because they're unknown quality - they attract a lower price.

Were Mr Adventurer to sell the parts to Bob the Blacksmith, then Bob the Blacksmith could make the epic sword with his quality standards and reputation, and thus sell it for a higher price.

if Mr Adventurer spends a few years making good swords, and develops a brand and gets reviews, then he could get a good price.

Comment: +1, but also worth mentioning operating costs and opportunity costs to the adventurer.  Professional smith in guild keeps forge at operating temperature all the time and smiths take turns, therefore fuel and other time-based operating costs are minimised per item.  Adventurer has to set up forge plus workshop, get forge to operating temperature etc to make one item, operating cost for one item probably 2x or 3x that of smith.  Adventurer then has opportunity cost - time spent for low profit for one item compared to same time for better profit killing and looting from monsters.

Comment: It can explain why break-even cost of sword made by an adventurer is higher than market price. But the question is different. Market price of the sword is lower than market price of raw materials needed for production of said swords (i.e. metal ingots ). I don't see how this answer explains such curious predicament.

Comment: @user161005 It explains why the max price is lower than parts for a new untrusted entrant into a market. Imagine "Dominos pizza" starts making airliners. Airlines wont trust it and the first to take a gamble will have a max price that's significantly discounted, lower than the cost of the parts in all likelihood, to represent that risk.

Comment: @Ash Now it makes sense, thank you!

Comment: This is not consistent with the 'standard world of fantasy RPG videogame', though. Most fantasy RPGs feature level-based craft systems: One needs to reach a certain level in crafting to be able to craft a specific item. In other words, Bob the Blacksmith and Mr Adventurer will craft identical items from the same set of ingredients if they have the same crafting level or use the same recipe. MC's reputation with various NPC factions may affect prices. But it is not related to the quality of items.

Comment: @Otkin standard world of a fantasy RPG videogame =/= standard fantasy RPG videogame.

Comment: This was the answer I came to see with one caveat: there is an opportunity cost lost when creating something. If I create a sword of fire and an adventurer really needs a sword of ice. My ingredients could have really helped with the creation of his needed weapon but my crafting of a fire sword does not. Unless our adventurer is getting commissions, it is probably better to sell the materials so they don't go to waste.

Comment: @user161005  Because the OP is asking this question from the perspective of the main character (aka: player character), then what is true of a standard fantasy RPG videogame will also be true of the standard world of a fantasy RPG videogame as it relates to the player character.  The OP does not want to know why a random NPC adventurer gets so little for an artifact, he wants to know why the player character gets paid so little.  This means you need to look at the world in context of what is true of the Player Character which is all the things that are true of the video game.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 This is a video game world, not the real world. In a typical video game, the Player Character can get perfectly milled wooden boards by punching a tree and can craft a powerful weapon in the middle of the woods using nothing but a hammer.  So these operating costs don't really apply in most video games.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Wait, but I'm the OP ...

Comment: This answer seems to be missing the possibility that an adventurer could make a better item but still not make a profit due to opportunity costs. The prices of the reagents doesn't change if you are selling it to a grand master craftsman or an apprentice craftsman so quality of the final product shouldn't really matter. It is also ignoring the fact that you can fail crafting an item and if an adventurer fails they lose everything but if they sell the materials to a craftsman they lose nothing if the craftsman fails.

Comment: @user161005  If your world does not actually follow the mechanics of a videogame world, then you should probably specify this just as a "standard fantasy world" or a "video game setting you are making into a book/move/etc".   Videogame worlds have very different rules than other mediums because they tend to approach things like time, tools, prerequisites, and quality very differently than other settings.

Comment: But if your setting is a videogame, trying to fit real-world explanations can actually draw attention to the parts of your worldbuilding that don't make since.  So if you try to justify market values based on things that don't really apply to your Player Character, then you are just drawing attention to the unrealistic details that you want your audience to ignore/accept.

Comment: The above comment is understated and crucial to worldbuilding.  If it's completely untethered from reality, it makes no sense and no one will want to inhabit it.  So you have to base it on reality and decide which aspects to simulate, approximate, or obfuscate.  That balance is different for every game and affects how accurate a given analogy is for it (hence so much back and forth.)

Comment: A lot of this could be summed up with one very specific concept from economics: specialization of labor.

Specifically, look at the difference between something that a software developer who does woodworking as a hobby compared to a master woodworker's work.

In the end, that's what makes this answer so viscerally correct. It's directly paralleled in the real world, unlike many other aspects of fantasy worlds.

Comment: This answer is always true in reality. Yarn has a fixed cost, but the sweater your grandma knits doesn't sell for $125 at Neiman Marcus, does it?  And that's due to a combination of renown and a skill.

Game worlds approximate this to different degrees, generally for a better playing experience through consistency with less development effort.  E.g. it would be frustrating if the durability deduction on a weapon depended on a hidden stat like craftperson's skill.  And even moreso if it's also a hidden stat on the vendors, since frequently multiple vendors will sell the same Iron Longsword.

Comment: TL;DR: Same reason you pay a health professional instead of removing your appendix.

Comment: Note that in certain video games, the first statement may appear to be untrue as a result of cultural differences.  This can be seen in RPGs which consider "adventuring for ingredients" to be a part of the craftsman's trade, such as, e.g., _Summon Night: Swordcraft Story_ or the _Atelier_ series.  It is important to note that in this sort of game, the protagonist is typically a specialised craftsman **first** and an adventurer **second**, rather than the more typical "adventurer dabbling in crafting."  These games are thus proof of the rule, rather than the exceptions they appear to be.

Comment: @Nosajimiki "Videogame worlds have very different rules than other mediums" - This is very true. IRL crafting isn't just magically putting things together and they materialise into the result. But labour and resource costs of forging things is just an added layer of complexity that isn't necessarily any more fun. Even if it was streamlined down to "Resources + Money = Artifact", the player could be frustrated by the fact they're expected to calculate how profitable selling an item is when it could ignore cost and just tell you how much you make from selling the item.

Answer (score 76):

### Because you are selling to shops, not to adventurers

I agree with the accepted answer in most settings, but not in the context of the genre.  In many games, the best weapons are the ones you craft yourself; so, there is some assumption that your character either is a capable artificer, or you can at least level up that skill to become one.

However, when you look at the shop systems of most games you will notice that most items sell for WAY less than you could buy them for.  Most video games do this purely as a balancing mechanic, but there is a real world explanation for how this kind of thing sometimes happens.

In many games, a \$1000 sword may only sell for \$100, even when you are selling it right back to the guy you bought it from that same day.  This confirms that craftsmanship is not the guiding principle here. However, in the real world, wholesale is typically 50-85% of retail meaning that the guy who actually made that \$1000 sword was paid by the shop owner \$500-850 to make it. Videogames general do not define these values so we will assume the real-world values here.

So, why would a shop owner pay the blacksmith up to \$850 for the same sword that he would only pay you \$100 for? You see, the shop owner can not keep high quality wares in stock without the blacksmith; otherwise, adventurers would just always buy his best stuff and fill his shop with worthless junk they are selling, and his shop would very quickly be filled with nothing but a giant pile of worthless goblin spears.

The shop owner also knows that he needs to keep the blacksmith busy enough to make sure that the blacksmith does not provide his wares else ware.  So, lets say you are a shop owner who knows a guy who makes +3 longswords.  If you can buy up and sell all of those +3 longswords then you can charge a premium on them, but if you can only buy 1/2 of them because you are also selling the stuff adventures are bringing in, then there is the risk that your blacksmith will start selling to the guy across the street from you too.  If this happens you have to be more competitive with your pricing on +3 longswords... and any other weapons that have a comparable value to a +3 longsword.

So, the reason shops pay so little for your artifacts is not that they are worth so little, but because you are not actually "selling" your sword to the shop at all.  What you are really doing is "trading it in". Consider a new car dealership.  Many dealerships buy way more used cars than they can sell, but no matter how shitty your old junker is, they will always offer you something for it if it helps them sell you a new car.  Likewise, you could come in with a 6 month old, top-end sports car that is worth more than anything on thier lot, and they still will not give you more than a small fraction of its worth because thier goal is not to buy your car, it is to sell you a new one.

So what is happening is that that your artifact level weapon is being sold following the same business practices they use to buy that stack of 10 goblin spears you also just walked in with.  The shop keeper knows that most of what he will buy from you is just going the the trash heap and that selling your good stuff puts his relationship with his blacksmith in jeopardy; so, he offsets the risk and waste of buying your stuff by only paying you a tiny fraction of its worth.

#### Why reagents don't follow this pattern:

The shop owner is perfectly happy to pay a fair wholesale price on any artifacting reagents you bring in because adventures ARE the expected wholesalers of these materials.  If you want a gryphon's feather or a hydra's venom, then everyone knows you buy that stuff from adventurers; so, the shop owner does not want to undercut your profits here.  He knows 100% that he can quickly and easily sell them to the blacksmith, and that he can only buy them from adventurers. So he pays you the wholesale rate of \$200 for the materials, which he then retails to the blacksmith for \$250.  It's easy pocket money for the shop owner, and it does not actually cut into his weapon sales.   Then the blacksmith uses those materials to make a sword he wholesales back to the shop owner for \$700.  Then the shop owner retails it for \$1000.  Everyone has made a profit, and more importantly, no one has risked thier supply chain in doing so.  In business: safe repeatable, low-profit transactions are called your "bread and butter" and they are way more important to staying in business than the occasional wind-fall transaction.

What you don't see as an adventurer is that the shop owner would never pay a blacksmith wholesale on reagents.  The blacksmith in the expected consumer of them just as the adventurer is the expected consumer of +3 longswords; so, when the blacksmith does need to offload an over-stock of reagents to the shopkeeper, the shopkeeper would only pay the trade-in rate of \$25 for them because it would be so hard to find someone else to sell them too.

Comment: Wonderful answer, makes perfect sense. And also somewhat explains why you can sell random stuff to anyone doing trade: They're giving you such a bad bargain that even the potion seller can turn some profit (or just break even) on whatever random weaponry you sell him. And if he just breaks even: well he attracted a potential high value customer (the Player) to his shop, so thats good enough

Comment: "then there is the risk that your blacksmith will start selling to the guy across the street from you too" I don't see how it makes sense. Even if the merchant buys all swords his competitor can come and say to the blacksmith "Next time you make swords - sell all of them to me, I will pay higher price than that cheapskate"

Comment: "selling your good stuff puts his relationship with his blacksmith in jeopardy;" I don't see how this is true. On contrary, it puts the merchant in better bargaining position, as he needs the blacksmith less than without reselling the good stuff.

Comment: @user161005 the better bargaining position applies to the modern world with its online deliveries. In the average fantasy world, your city has one blacksmith, and if you do something that makes them hate your guts, they will not sell to you, and you will go out of business. Adventurers are notoriously unreliable sources of weapons; the blacksmith is reliable. You need reliable to survive, you don't want to go bankrupt just because the adventurer who sold you random stuff got eaten by a grue.

Comment: The shopkeeper also has mouths to feed.  He's not going to buy something for more than he in turn can sell it for, or that he can't even sell.  Games approximate this, e.g. by letting you sell whatever to whoever for convenience.  In that case, you can pretend potion person is just being nice and at any point could walk over to the blacksmith and trade those iron ingots for the price they just paid you, effectively buying them on his/her behalf.

Comment: And I don't think this was mentioned, but is applicable since we're talking about selling for resale: the shopkeeper knows he's selling pristine merchandise from the blacksmith.  Lord only knows where your equipment has been, or what it's been through.

Shopkeep: "This sword is unused, right?"
Sword: _Obviously of foreign make, faintly glowing._
Blood-and-dirt-covered Adventurer: "Yeah, sure."

Comment: @user161005 In economics, there is a thing called Game Theory in which each business will modify his products and sales based on the choices of the competition.   While Game Theory was not formalized until the mid-20th century, it has been intuitively practiced since the beginning of time.  Basically, if the guy across the street offers more for +3 swords, it means he needs to sell them for more, or at a smaller profit.  All things being the same, they would compete over prices/volumes/etc trying to collect the largest possible profit based on the other guy's sales strategy...

Comment: but if only one guy is besties with the Blacksmith, then the other guy is almost guaranteed to loose because he needs to offer over and above what that relationship is worth to the blacksmith.  Instead, the other guy may find it more worth while to buddy up with the bowyer so he can get exclusive rights to those awesome +3 longbows instead of loosing money squabbling over longswords.

Comment: This is really insightful and thought provoking. Thank you for that answer! I've just joined to upvote it.

Comment: I would consider the _Etrian Odyssey_ series to be an exceptional example of this practice.  You deliver materials to the store (which is itself run by the crafting guild), who in turn use those materials to create items.  Purchasing rare items (or any items, in earlier games) depletes the store's inventory, which is restocked as you sell them the necessary materials again.  It establishes a clear chain of supply and demand, and also shows the store markup (in that equipment is typically more expensive than the sum of its materials).

Answer (score 24):

I'll take an example from RuneScape, a game where this phenomenon is very common.

**Other players want the materials to train their skills.**

If you want to make armor out of steel, you must first learn to make armor out of iron. You must make a few hundred pieces of armor out of iron before you're good enough to attempt making armor out of steel.

This creates a demand by aspiring blacksmiths for enough iron ingots to make hundreds of pieces of iron armor, and a supply of iron armor that surpasses the demand for that armor by soldiers and other players. Thus, the price of iron ingots is high and the price of iron armor is low.

Comment: Also: Because players created crafts to train their skills, that _also_ devalues the resulting crafts. If every apprentice is cranking out "Magic Armor" for practice, then they end up basically worthless.  Runes in Runescape are like this. Hard to craft, but you get experience points.  They're virtually worthless to sell though, because they're so easy to come by.

Comment: The way this makes sense is that a fully trained blacksmith can make high-end armour which is in demand and profitable. They essentially pay thousands of gold pieces for training (buying the raw materials and throwing away the finished "practice" armour).

Comment: Ha, RuneScape was my first thought as well.

Answer (score 16):

**The MC isn't the best at crafting and pays the price of opportunity cost.**

I'm not a painter. I can take a bunch of expensive paints and craft a terrible painting, and it will be worth *less* than the raw materials. I'm also not a tailor. If I tried to make a garment out of an expensive fabric, I would just ruin the cloth. I am also not a jeweler. Given a bunch of gold and gems, I'm not going to be able to make anything that's worth more than the raw materials alone.

Crafting only adds value commensurate with the skill of the craftsperson. If you don't have the tools and skills to turn raw material into finished goods, you're at best wasting your time trying by making something that isn't any more valuable than what you started with, and at worst, wasting the raw materials because you don't know how to use them properly.

Even if you have the tools and skills needed to craft, in many cases it's still *more profitable* to let a specialist do it for you due to opportunity cost and a thing called **comparative advantage**. Basically, you can craft an item yourself, but the time it takes to do so could be spent doing something else that would have been *even more profitable*. Here's an example:

Suppose you have collected 10 Foos for a Bar potion, and you can either sell those 10 Foos to the potion maker for $10, or brew them into a potion yourself and sell it for \$20. But in the time it took you to brew the potion, you could have collected 20 more Foos, which could sell for an additional \$20, rather than earning only an extra \$10 by brewing the potion. If this is the case, you'll be more profitable by selling raw ingredients than by brewing potions, despite the fact that the crafted item sells for more!

What's really interesting is that this arrangement is also more profitable for the potion maker - if he's more skilled at brewing potions than finding ingredients (e.g. if he can only collect 5 Foos in the time it takes him to brew a potion), you will both be more profitable if you only find raw ingredients and he only brews the finished product. Both of you should only do the one thing you're best at, which for most adventurers, is not crafting a wide array of useful items.

Comment: I was supprised that I had to scroll down so for to find the first mention of opportunity costs. While the other answers provide good ideas, this is one contains the real reason, especially as the OP explicitly mentiones that the artefacts crafted by the adventurer have higher market prices than their ingredients.

Comment: You also have quality, a smith who smiths every day is going to be far better at it than an adventure who only does it once a fortnight.

Comment: This doesn't apply for most role-playing games (which is what the OP is asking about). As soon as a crafter learns to make X they can do it perfectly. A few, like EVE or Albion, let you specialize and require complex facilities -- in them a devoted crafter can make an X much cheaper and faster, so this answer would apply.

Comment: @OwenReynolds True, there is no opportunity cost when crafting is instant and perfect. Another aspect to consider that's present in some games, though, is that crafting may only be possible in certain locations (at your home base, in a city, etc.). If you can collect Foos in the forest and sell them there, it may never be worthwhile to spend the time trekking to a distant crafting station.

Answer (score 15):

Why does a farmer sell the wheat to the miller instead of milling it and selling the flour?

Why does the miller sell the flour to the baker instead of baking bread and selling the bread?

Because any additional step requires time, resources, and knowledge that one can hardly have, together with capital to make the necessary investment: running a mill is profitable if a large pool of users can be served, so that the needed large quantities can be processed, and so on.

Same goes for your adventurers.

Comment: "Why does a farmer sell the wheat to the miller instead of milling it and selling the flour?" This is called vertical integration. And it exists in real world. This raises a question, why does it exists in our world and not in the fantasy world described above?

Comment: @user161005 In a typical fantasy world, there isn't a lot of concentration of wealth. There are nobles who'd have liquid cash to spend on vertical integration but they're relatively few and they probably have better (or at least more urgent) things to spend it on, like armies and tournaments.

Comment: @Cadence "there isn't a lot of concentration of wealth" I think you wanted to say, that there are too few people wealthy enough to be able to afford vertical integration. As for concentration of wealth, wealth in typical fantasy world is more concentrated than in our world, as there are very few wealthy individuals and the rest of population is either poor or very poor.

Comment: @user161005 Modern 1st world countries are **exceedingly** wealthy compared to medieval times. Just look at birth rates. Having a baby die is a tragedy, not "Tuesday". As a homeless, jobless person in North America countries, they have access to food, shelter, and medicine leagues better than what most commoners have in medieval times. Note that this does not justify at all that homeless are not "poor"; they are, but relative to medieval times, they are extremely well off, because medieval times are atrociously bad.

Comment: A homeless, jobless person in North America has access to food, shelter, and medicine leagues better than all commoners, and nobles, and royalty had in medieval times, and any other time and place before well into the 19th century.

Comment: @Mary the modern homeless person definitely has better access to medicine than medieval royalty, but I'm not convinced on food, and confident you're wrong on shelter. I'd much sooner live in the Palace of Fontainbleau, Buda Castle, or the Tower of London, than in a tent city.

Comment: They can go to a homeless shelter at need. Which would have central heating.   As for food, the canning industry alone ensures that.

Comment: @user161005 it doesn't exist in fantasy worlds because fantasy protagonists (especially in computer games) aren't constrained by time and effort. In real life, the cost (money, time, effort) needed to become a master baker means you simply can't be a master smith as well. A computer game hero, on the other hand, can be a master smith and a master baker and a master herbalist and a master whatever - all while also being a master sword fighter and a mster spellcaster and a master cutpurse, and so on.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker Vertical integration doesn't exist in fantasy world because fantasy protagonists can be masters at everything at once? I don't see how it can make any sense.

Answer (score 14):

### Diverse Uses:

This is a bit like the 'Minecraft' version of an answer. If you have high-quality steel, do you already know what it will be made into? Sure, it COULD be made into a sword, but maybe the person buying the steel wants four knives. Maybe they make a specialty tool out of it. If you take the steel and make a sword, you can only sell it to a person looking for a sword. With the steel, everyone in the market for good steel is a potential buyer.

**Multiple uses:** It's exactly the same for your adventurer. Maybe 95% of dragon hide is made into magical books. So you make a magical book out of it. Books are easy to transport, small, and have a ready market. But sometimes, people want dragon hide to fix a book. Sometimes they want to make dragon-scale armor. Occasionally, a rich noble wants to make a dragon leather jacket to show off just how wealthy and powerful he/she is. Because most dragon hide is used for books, the supply for these other applications is much smaller. Transporting the whole dragon hide might be quite a task. Dragons might hunt people carrying around a dragon hide. But the profit from doing so is bigger than doing the safe and easy thing.

**Custom items:** Further, those crafting items are usually doing so for their own use. Those crafting for others are likely doing it for a specific client. Either way, if you're making a sword for a specific person, you make the blade a certain length for that person. A magic book with a person's name on it is specific to them and special (like naming an item in Minecraft). The amount of money someone is spending on a magical artifact means they want something special, not just generic. If YOU make the artifact, it's a (fill in the blank magic tryptic). If the artifact is made for a specific person, it's THE TRYPTIC OF MABINOGION!

**Guaranteed quality:** Not to mention that anyone buying an artifact wants to be sure they are getting exactly what they think they're buying. You could have skimped on dragon hide and made the book out of mixed strips of dragon and gorgon hide. Sure it works, but there's the rare chance of a magical misfire turning you to stone. Perhaps it costs money to confirm that an item does what it is supposed to do (like the *identify* spell from D&D). Maybe gorgon hide passes for dragon hide, but no one could fake a whole dragon hide. The world is full of cheap knock-offs of expensive goods, so why take a risk?

**Economy of scale:** Some of the ingredients in an artifact are easier to make, grow or harvest than others. Perhaps guilds are able to grow the rare and special herbs that must never see direct sunlight and have to be harvested only by the light of a full moon. They do it all the time, and cheaply. They use them for their internal market (artifact making) and never sell them to keep others from making artifacts. Your adventurer might need to make multiple attempts to do so successfully, and at great cost. Since the adventurer will sell the herbs, they still are profitable (since the guild won't sell), but the guild undercuts the cost of the artifact by making/obtaining one of the ingredients cheaply.

**Specialization:** Adventurers are going to be really good at killing monsters. So they get lots of the most expensive/hard to obtain goods. There's lots of profit in this. But adventurers spending their time growing herbs, making spell components, and breaking into the graves of murderers to cook off their fat and make magic tallow candles that must light the enchanting ceremonies are doing things they get less money for. An herbalist will grow herbs better, a grave-robber will dig up corpses more cheaply (and assume the risks of such reprehensible behavior), and why is an adventurer buying the special tools to enchant from a blacksmith when the enchanter already has a set?

Comment: Economy of scale:  Adding to this: an experienced artificer can probably craft way more efficient. Especially with the very valuable components maybe it just needs a sprinkle at the exact right second instead of the whole thing. An adventurer won't know this and use the whole thing. The potion in the end does the same thing, but the Artificer makes 20 out of the same rare resource

Comment: "Multiple uses:" I don't understand how this makes it more profitable for an adventurer to sell ingredients than to craft and then sell an artifact. Can you explain, please?

Comment: @user161005 Market economics. The more people who are available/want to buy your product (demand), the higher the prices, because lots of people want your single product (supply). once your product is on it's final form, the number of people who want it is limited to those wanting the final form. As a raw material, everyone who can make something from your product is a potential customer. But this doesn't work if there is only one possible use for your product.

Comment: @DWKraus But then if an artefact is produced, then its price will incorporate opportunity cost. Like if you can make 10 knives or 1 sword and market for knives is really hot right now, what do you do? You either do not produce a sword and produce 10 knives instead or you **do** produce a sword, but at such price, that successfully selling it will bring you at the least the same profit as selling 10 knives would.

Comment: @user161005 Not following you. To extend the example: If you make the sword (artifact) but when you go to sell the sword, no one is buying swords because knives are all the rage, then you get a poor price for the sword, and can't make knives instead. The steel (raw material) would bring a good price for knife making, and you wouldn't be out the cost of making a sword that isn't selling. Or you could make knives at that point. Either way, the raw material (steel) is a safe bet that can apply to all uses. Assuming similar manufacturing prices, which are likely more expensive for an adventurer.

Comment: "Either way, the raw material (steel) is a safe bet that can apply to all uses." So there will be more people selling steel, meaning that supply for steel will go up and prices for steel will go down, until it's balanced by demand for steel from people who make knives and swords (for simplicity's sake I assume that people can make only knives or swords out of steel). And they will buy steel at point when it has price low enough to make production of knives/swords profitable.

Comment: @user161005 Yes, but the same rule applies to the finished product. And the demand for swords could be low, so if you make all your steel into swords before selling, you are limited to supplying the demand for swords (not so good in peaceful times). Knives are made in all times, so keeping your product in the raw material form allows greater flexibility to meet demands.

Answer (score 10):

In today's world, we make more profit selling craft parts than we do selling the actual crafts. Who we are selling to are the hobbyists, the people who have the spare time to play with making things and the money to buy the parts. Yet, if one were to try to sell the crafts, few people want to pay the price needed to support the crafts person. People don't want to buy the crafts as much as buy the experience of making the crafts. (See the profits that Hobby Lobby is making vs the profits that crafts people make. The average seller on ETSY is making $1/hr.) Same way with art. Few artists can make art full time and survive. Most make their money by teaching art and make their art on the side. In the gold rushes, the people who made the money were those who supplied the miners, not those who rushed there with gold in their eyes.

So, your adventurer will make a lot more by selling the parts, the story, and the hope of adventure to people who want to dream.

Comment: Exactly! I feel that real-world approaches add a lot of verisimilitude to a story. Consider what we typically pay for socks. Would anyone reading this spend 50 bucks on a single pair of socks? That hardly covers the price of the fleece used. Include time to card, spin, dye, knit, weave in, and block, and it'd be well over up in the thousands of dollars per handmade sock. Some might pay that for charity, and others for a prestigious maker's mark; but then they aren't really buying the socks, but rather the charity or mark. Nobody would buy a thousand buck handmade sock that's "just a sock".

Comment: ... and the above doesn't include costs like the space to make the socks in, the equipment used (carding combs, spinning wheel, dye and vats, needles, blocking mats & pins, and more I'm forgetting), or the training to learn those skills.

Answer (score 8):

**Because there are more valuable things to make than the artifact out of the materials**

Making an artifact is inefficient with the materials it needs.  Sure, bathing the final product in a bucket of dragon's blood really bakes in the power, but the residuum that leaches off makes all the blood that's left afterward useless for most other purposes.  The real money is in non-adventurer goods!  Just a few drops of fresh dragon's blood suspended in a mixture of herbs and oils can be sprayed around a house to keep bugs and vermin out for over a month, which not only works great but also means you get repeat customers!

When you add together the greater demand and broader consumer base, it's a sellers market for things that your average adventurer just wouldn't care about.  On top of that, while I imagine there aren't a *ton* of artifacts available, there also aren't a lot of adventurers of the right caliber to be picking them up so it's harder to interest shopkeepers in stocking something that may sit on the shelves for years before seeing a real return on investment while also being an attractive target for thieves.

Comment: Similarly (too close to post as an answer) I might be able to make a tasty stew given a load of herbs and bits of dead animal, but an apothecary can make a healing potion. Which is more valuable?

Answer (score 7):

It is the economics of experience, which has value.

When I have ingredients and transform them into a thing, I create two portions of value:  The thing, and the experience.  I consume the value of the ingredients and some value of my labor.  If I am a novice, the value of my labor is low.

When I sell the thing, its value is lower because I retain the value of the experience.

V(ingredients)+V(labor)=V(thing)+V(experience)

Depending on where you are in a game, those values change.  Since one is typically gaining experience so that one will "level-up", the V(experience) is dear and the V(labor) is zero.  Thus, the V(thing) will be lower than the V(ingredients).

Comment: I believe this was an effect I observed when I played in World of Warcraft. The auction price of raw ingredients was always higher than the crafted goods produced from those ingredients, because the crafters were producing a surplus of goods, purely to improve their own crafting skills.

Comment: This is what happens in Runescape, as pointed out by Alexandre Aubrey's answer.

Comment: @user253751 Alexandre Aubrey's (very good) answer is focused pretty tightly on dynamic economies often found in MMOs. The "economics of experience" here is general enough to be applicable to many styles of RPG, even an old-school single-player (J)RPG where prices are simply set by the developers.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a medieval flavour: **because they do not have the monopoly for the artefacts**. In our modern economies, we take for granted that if you want to make a widget then, provided you have the means to do so and you comply with local standards, you can do so and then it's up to you to compete with other people selling widgets.

In most places, and most times in the medieval world, *it did not work like that*. Only the miller could mill grain, in fact if you wanted to mill your own with your own grindstone for your own use, you might have to pay the miller a fee for not using his services. You needed permissions to trade in cities, and could be granted monopolies on production or trade in pretty much any good you can imagine. Often the right to grant these permissions was sub-contracted to powerful guilds, and woe-betide anyone foolish enough to cross them.

Answer (score 4):

## Guilds have the infrastructure to craft at volume, thus getting more value out of individual ingredients that an adventure would not be able to, given crafting requirements

Take, for example, a herbal potion involving two herbs to make a single healing potion.

For an adventurer, that sounds fine, they can make that, and they have the two herbs to do so.

A guild looks at that recipe, notices it involves breaking one of the herbs in half, and tossing one of the halves, and says "Wait - I can make *two* herbal potions while only using three herbs!"

So that starts to mask some of the actual savings a guild member can pass on to their clients that an adventurer can't meet, as the costs of individual ingredients are in higher demand because there is more to get out of volume of ingredients, but there's also ancillary costs that can be bundled the same way.

When brewing those potions, an adventurer needs to boil the water it's being mixed in, and stir it all together, and pour it out into one flask. A guild can take a larger pot, boil it all more or less the same, then put in two potions worth, or four, or fifteen potions worth, then pour it out into multiple flasks and get multiple potions out. For the same effort of starting a flame, and near ignorable amount of water usage increased. As a bonus, doing so means they still only have to clean one alchemist's pot to prepare it for another set of potions.

You can apply similar efficiency savings for weapons (What's that? This would give us leftover, unusable iron to make this one sword? Use that leftover iron to make another sword, rather than throw it out, while it's still hot.), that can make the savings on individual artefacts outweigh the costs of making an artifact out of one set of ingredients.

Comment: In other words, economies of scale.

Comment: In short, yes - but there's both a material economy at play and the labor economy at play - if I can make 15 health potions at the same time as an adventurer takes to make one health potion, the unit cost per potion can be lower, including the wage of the person making the potions, and the costs of the materials per potion, they can sell more for cheaper, or even water them down with cheaper materials/alloys that allow for more product for less materials.

Comment: @user161005 which is the real-life answer to your question too. Specialised factories can extract way more value out of the same ingredients than a single worker.

Answer (score 4):

## Making the artifact isn't hard.

The materials are hard to procure, and the craftsmanship is time-consuming, but not particularly demanding of a particular skill level.  The protagonist's time is better spent doing something he specializes in--procuring the materials.

In addition, the artifact may be like a Jedi lightsaber, where each user takes pride in the tradition of crafting his own specialized and individual version.

There may be several tradeoffs in the actual design of the artifact, which each user makes according to their own preference.  Of possible use is mandatory customization, i.e., the finished artifact must be designed for a particular individual--think e.g. fingerprint-recognizing guns, but without the programmability.

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons why it is more profitable to sell the reagents than the final product even if the adventurer has a higher skill and can make a better item.

1. Failures: First and foremost is if it is possible to fail the adventurer would lose out on everything and not make any money. If there is a chance for failure why take that risk yourself? Leave the risk of failing to someone who crafts for a living.
2. Time to craft: This is also another big one, will the adventurer be able to make more money harvesting more materials or crafting an item? Unless the crafting adds a lot of value they are likely going to make more from harvesting more materials instead of crafting.
3. Equipment needed: Unless the equipment needed to craft the items is small, cheap and relatively portable the extra costs are going to add up. If the equipment is large and expensive the costs to store it and keep it safe are going to add up and eat into the profits. After all who is going to use or protect it when the adventurer is out adventuring?
4. Uses for the items: Some of the reagents might be used for multiple items and may sell for better prices in different areas. As the adventurer travels they may find it to be more profitable to sell the reagents in areas where they are more valuable.

In the end the reason why it is more profitable to sell the reagents than a final item comes down to lost opportunity costs. In order for an adventurer to make an item give up doing something else. If what they give up doing could make them more money it doesn't matter how much the item would sell for because they still lose out in the end.

Comment: Theoretically the risk of failure should be included in the price. Unless the adventurer has a higher-than-average risk of failure.

Comment: @user253751Building the costs of failures into the price only works if you are crafting on a larger scale. It doesn't matter if you profit in the long run if the failures from a few combines means you don't make or lose money on your current adventure.

Answer (score 3):

### Taxes and guilds

The production and usage of the artifacts is obviously a thing of importance for the economy, and therefore desirable for the nobility to have control over, so they made a deal with crafters. Crafters organize into guilds, follow regulations, and can therefore afford the luxury of selling their products with no drawbacks. But if you're not playing by the guild rules? Then you must pay for that. Quite literally. Various taxes and fees are applied to you in order to discourage people from making and selling artifacts outside of guilds control, resulting in you getting significantly less money from selling one. I've heard some governors crank the fees so high that you give up as much as 60% of the money made from the deal to the crown. And guilds are naturally very protective and all hush-hush about their methods and procedures (think glassmakers of Venice), so getting into one isn't trivial either - they very much do not like outsiders.

Comment: I don't undestand the benefit that nobles have from this guild system.

Comment: Nobles control the guilds, who control the production of important items. The heads of the guilds are most likely _are_ nobles.

Comment: What benefits do nobles get from this control? Control in itself can't be a benefit.

Comment: @user161005 They get a cut of the money. Induction fees and training fees for people joining the guild. Maybe a yearly fee to stay a member of the guild. Plus the fees on anyone who isn't a member of the guild... Plus they have a captive market for any resources they have that are used in making whatever the guild makes, because obviously the guild buys from them first. Maybe they get first choice on buying stuff, too--if you are trying to buy some clothing but the nobles at the head of the clothing guild want fancy clothes, you are out of luck and will have to wait.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers seem to assume that somehow the MC has the ability to actually craft the items, at some level. In many computer games at least this is simply not so. Perhaps you can make a few minor items, but actual artifact-grade enchantment is well outside of the game mechanic.

Morrowind for instance has a rich and exploit-laden crafting system, but even with the most blatantly over-the-top enchanter you can't produce anything *truly* potent. The best non-magical base materials in the game - high-end non-magical weapons and the like - will take only a relatively minor player enchantment, even though many high grade magical items are available whose apparent base item is low- to mid-grade. The artifacts in the game, even silly things like the Boots of Blinding Speed, are simply not possible for the player to craft.

The same is true in a lot of other games out there, where player crafting is more of a fun add-on to the hack-n-slash grindfest that is the base gameplay. Ooh, I can spend 1,000gp worth of hard to find reagents to enchant an item that gives less actual utility than just dropping the coin on a mid-level item? Let's do that, it'll be fun!

Especially when it comes to fantasy games, the lore is full of stories about ancient artificer clans - Dwarven smiths, Elven magecrafters, etc. - who have spent centuries or millennia honing their craft. Their apprentices are able to churn out magic items you can't even dream of... but then, some of those apprentices have been working for decades learning the secrets of that one item they're still trying to perfect. Your character isn't going to pick up that kind of skill in a couple of months of weekend play, or even several months of daily focus on just enchanting one item. At best you'll only ever be an amateur, a dabbler in the art.

Perhaps more relevant to the question is trade secrets. Every trade has them, and they're jealously guarded. All you have access to as a dabbler is the publicly available recipes, blueprints and what have you. Everyone knows that it takes powdered cockatrice bile, a steal at only 500gp per gram, to inscribe the empowering runes that defend against death magics... even though the primary supplier of gear empowered by those runes has figured out how to do it with much cheaper alchemical residue infused with a spell created by one of their researchers.

Crafting in games is - or at least should be - about balance. If the crafting system allows players to create abusively powerful gear then it will be abused mercilessly. Limit it too harshly and it will be just a cute side game that only a few will bother with. The balance mostly falls out around the 'useful but not overpowered' mark, if it isn't actively crippled to avoid uber-artifacts flooding the game and destroying the economics. Because nobody likes it when players create items that let them (or their friends) one-hit the game boss.

Comment: The reason the answers assume the MC has that ability is because... the question states the MC has that ability

Answer (score 1):

If you want a game case where you can sell materials and finished goods and that you have finished goods selling for less than the materials, with same ability of your manufacturing than of others and same access to materials:

Eve Online - most of stuff there is manufactured, and materials are mined. Reprocessing (now) gives less materials than was put in to make that item. There was a historic reason and 2 reasons remaining why sometimes ammo was cheaper than ingredients for making it:

1. (main historic reason a decade ago): Noobs entering the game sometimes see manufacturing is the biggest money making machine, so they decide to mine the minerals, then use them to make the ammo to sell (other things require a lot of starting capital). But because they are so fresh they forgot to include mineral cost to the ammo cost as they didn't pay for it directly (only with time used for mining).
2. Freeing tied-up money - you have billions of bullets you want to sell, and someone else also does, leading to a price war. If you wait with your pricing at break-even or with small profit and let the other undercut you, you have billions of money locked in that stock. Yes, you will eventually make profit, but you have opportunity costs too - this money could be used to make say weapons or ships to sell with much greater profit. So, sometimes you might opt to just dump your stock at below mineral price.
3. Things have buy and sell price and you actually make profit by trading - median price is break-even or even a slight loss. You can instantly buy minerals for X or sell them for Y<X. Likewise for ammo. If you buy minerals and then make ammo and sell it, you lose money. But you can put buy or sell orders too - so, you put a low buy order on minerals and high sell order on ammo you are making and profit in the end (excluding scenario 2). Reason why you even need to manufacture is in volume of trade - usually, slightly more people are selling minerals directly to the highest buy order, and much more people are buying ammo from the lowest sell order.

Point 1 can be permanent - there is an idiot born every minute that believes loss on sale can be made up in volume.
Point 2 cannot be permanent, as nobody sane would keep making this ammo unless they are just trying to mess with someone else.
Point 3 can be permanent too - it happens incredibly often in real world.

Comment: I don't understand #1 and #3 in your answer. "But because they are so fresh they forgot to include mineral cost to the ammo cost as they didn't pay for it directly (only with time used for mining)." What? " If you buy minerals and then make ammo and sell it, you lose money." Why? "But you can put buy or sell orders too - so, you put a low buy order on minerals and high sell order on ammo you are making and profit in the end" What? "

Comment: "Reason why you even need to manufacture is in volume of trade - usually, slightly more people are selling minerals directly to the highest buy order, and much more people are buying ammo from the lowest sell order." What?

Comment: @user161005 You mine minerals and in an hour get enough for say 1k bullets. You could sell those minerals for 10k. But fresh idiots sometimes forgot to add this 10k material cost to their price calculation (as they mined minerals themselves it was free for them - they didn't buy them), and they opted to sell the bullets for 9k - thinking they made 9k profit by selling bullets.

Comment: @user161005 There are market orders, eg someone is selling 10k minerals for 100k of money, another is buying 10k for 90k of money. If you have 10k minerals, you can decide to directly sell that for 90k. But you can opt to put another sell order for say 99k. If someone is buying, they can either buy your order for 99k directly, or set buy order for say 91k. Etc etc. There is usually a ~10% gap between buy and sell orders that have meaningful volume - so if you are just buying outright, and selling outright, you are earning ~20% less than someone who put the highest buy and lowest sell order.

Comment: @user161005 And this 20% is the difference between losing money and making money. Now, finally for the last "what", you probably notice that here you could simply earn money by trading "I could just put a bit higher buy order and a bit lower sell order and earn money, no need to make anything". Here, the thing is that few are selling ammo to the buy orders - most manufacturers prefer to earn as much as possible and set up sell orders instead. So, you can't trade ammo much. But you can sell a lot of ammo to people that just buy whatever is the cheapest at the moment.

Comment: @ZizyArcher: Note that the noobs actually *did* make 9k profit selling bullets. Yes, opportunity cost is important to consider if we want to maximize profit, but the argument that "you could have made more elsewhere therefore you're actually losing money" is invalid. There's always some other way I could have made more money than I am in real life, but that doesn't mean I'm going bankrupt. As long as my incoming money is higher than my outgoing money, I'm making a profit.

Comment: @MichaelS If you ignore opportunity cost - you decrease overall wealth that you have. So this can not be profit by definition. Suppose you found a rare gem on a beach. Your overall wealth increased by \$100 000 as this is market value of said gem. If you then sold this gem for \$1, your overall wealth decreased by \$99 999. You didn't make \$1 profit ("it was free for me to find this gem"), you decreased your wealth. "As long as my incoming money is higher than my outgoing money, I'm making a profit." Not all wealth comes directly in shape of dollars. You should consider flows of wealth.

Comment: @user161005: That's a common misconception, but life doesn't work that way. Otherwise, everyone has negative wealth and we're just getting poorer all the time, because there's always some way we could have made more wealth. Which is clearly absurd. If I have more money tomorrow than I had yesterday, I made a profit. (Yes, obviously material gains can be or lead to wealth and are worth considering, but it's not relevant to the point in contention. We just rephrase to something like "if I have more cool stuff tomorrow, I made a profit" and it's otherwise the same concept.)

Comment: @MichaelS "because there's always some way we could have made more wealth" Notice, I used market value. This is not about "theoretically I could have sold this box of matches for million dollars if I was very sly and very lucky". I was talking about **market** value of your property. So you're attacking a strawman here. "If I have more money tomorrow than I had yesterday, I made a profit." Not necessarily. If you sold your family castle worth millions of \$ for \$1000 you **decreased** your wealth, thus profit is negative.

Comment: @user161005: That's exactly what market value is: the hope that you can sell or trade one thing for something valuable. It isn't real until you actually have that valuable in your possession. Yes, there's often a great deal of confidence in that hope, but there's a large difference between what might be and what is. As to your second point, that's an actual strawman. Again, clearly, money isn't the only form of wealth. That's irrelevant to the point. The point is that potential wealth (e.g., market value) isn't the same as actual wealth.

Comment: Example using your definitions: I have \$0 in my bank account. I pick up a gem worth \$100k. I sell it for \$1. According to you, I've lost \$99,999. I spend 200k days doing the same thing. Your math says I'm at -\$19.9998B. But my bank account shows me at \$200k. It's true that I'm \$19.9998B below where I might have been had I taken different actions in life. But I still have $200k in very real money. You're getting confused by the difference between "less positive" and "negative". You're seeing the -\$99k, but ignoring the +\$100k that preceded it.

Comment: @MichaelS "The point is that potential wealth (e.g., market value) isn't the same as actual wealth." Why do you think that money **is** your actual wealth, rather than potential wealth? After all, you can be living in a country with hyperinflation, where at the start of week you can buy 1 loaf of bread with x of money and at the end of week  - with 100x of money. Each month you could even have been paid more money - yet there would be less and less things you could buy with them as hyperinflation progressed.

Comment: @MichaelS Let's modify your example. Forget gems, each day for a week you miracously find three \$100 banknotes. You regularly burn two of them and put the third one on your banking account. Each day you gain \$300, destroy \$200 and add surviving \$100 banknote to your bank account. You literally burnt \$1400 dollars, yet there are additonal \$700 on your bank account. So by your logic we can conclude that burning money doesn't really mean we lose money

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127531/discussion-between-user161005-and-michaels).

Answer (score 0):

There are special agreements between guilds that sell ingredients and guilds of professional crafters. Namely, they provide guilds of professional crafters with ingredients at low prices. In return the guilds of crafters buy enormous quantities of said ingredients, so this is win-win. This lowers supply of ingredients for people who are not professional crafters (this includes people who are not crafters at all, as many ingredients have consumer value as standalone goods), making prices even higher for them. For this reason market price of an artefact is lower than total price at which an adventurer can sell its ingredients.

Comment: Wouldn't the crafters need to buy the same amount of ingredients regardless? And having an agreement to sell them at low prices would mean the adventurers would lose out on profit instead of make more.

Comment: @JoeW "Wouldn't the crafters need to buy the same amount of ingredients regardless? " Professional crafters buy more ingredients as price is cheaper.  "would mean the adventurers would lose out on profit instead of make more." Guilds of ingredients suppliers sell their ingredients exclusively to guilds of professional crafters. So it leaves place for ingredients market of out-of-guild crafters and people who use ingredients as final goods.

Comment: That isn't true at all crafters will make more money they more they make so they need to purchase as many materials as they can. Not only that at some point the price gets low enough that the adventurers lose money from selling them.

Comment: @JoeW "That isn't true" What exactly isn't true? This is basic economics, prices go down - demand goes up. Crafters outside guilds wouldn't be able to get such low prices, so they would need to rely on ingredients from alternative, more expensive, sources, like adventures. So they would have to sell their artefacts at higher prices, which means that demand for their production will be lower than for in-guild-crafters. "at some point the price gets low enough that the adventurers lose money from selling them." They sell ingredients at different market, to out-of-guild crafters.

Comment: Yes they will try ang get prices as low as possible but are you trying to claim that crafters won't make items or make money just because they can't get items cheaply enough? They will just set the prices for the items they make based on what it costs to make them. Adventurers are not going to want to sell cheaply as it is likely costing them their lives to make and they will not be selling in bulk individually. They are going to want to find ways to sell for a higher price and only sell for cheaper when there is no other way.

Comment: @JoeW Who says the professional crafters are using the same recipes?

Comment: @Corey Who says they are not? There isn't enough information in the question to say either way.